# Set the assembly default icon programmatically

Tags: c#, icons, .net-assembly

As from the title, I have an Windows Form project and I need to set the assembly icon for that file. The file is contained in an external dll and it is not an icon file.

Any way to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Not really, it is very rare to be able to get the write access you need to mess with the executable.  UAC stops this.

Answer (score 1):

Look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648004%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

The functions you'd want to be using are, as mentioned in the article are:

1. [BeginUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648030%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
3. [EndUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This concerns modifying the resources of an already compiled executable. I was searching the way to apply the Icon from the resource file during the build of the exe itself. Instead of specifying in project properties the default icon. Any idea?

Comment: @MaiOM Never seen anything like what you're asking before, I'm not really sure it's possible. Keep trying to find and if you won't I think the best option would be to find an alternative.